# Proving $f(V)=\mathrm{span}(f(\mathbf{v}_{1}),\dots, f(\mathbf{v}_{n})).$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I'm using the following definitions:

**Definition 1 (Linear Span)** Let $(V,+,\cdot)$ be a vector space over a field $\mathbb{K}$. The linear span of a subset $X\subseteq V$ is defined as
\begin{align*}
\mathrm{span} (X):=\left\{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i}\mathbf{v}_{i}\; \Bigg | \; n\in\mathbb{N},\;\lambda_{i}\in\mathbb{K},\; \mathbf{v}_{i}\in X\right\}
\end{align*}

**Definition 2 (Linear Map)**
Let $(V,+,\cdot)$ and $(W,\oplus,\odot)$ be vector spaces over a field $\mathbb{K}$. A map $\Phi:V\rightarrow W$ is called a linear map iff for all $\mathbf{u},\mathbf{v}\in V$ and all $\lambda \in\mathbb{K}$ we have

i) $\Phi(\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{v})= \Phi(\mathbf{u})\oplus\Phi(\mathbf{v})$ (additivity)

ii) $\Phi(\lambda\cdot \mathbf{u})=\lambda\odot \Phi(\mathbf{u})$ (homogeneity)

**I'm trying to prove the following:**
Let $V$ and $W$ be $\mathbb{K}$-vector spaces and let $\mathbf{v}_{1},\dots,\mathbf{v}_{n}\in V$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $V=\mathrm{span}(\mathbf{v}_{1},\dots,\mathbf{v}_{n})$. Then for all linear maps $f :V\rightarrow W$ we have
\begin{align*}\tag{a}
f(V)=\mathrm{span}(f(\mathbf{v}_{1}),\dots, f(\mathbf{v}_{n})).
\end{align*}

Using above definitions we immediately get
\begin{align*}\tag{b}
f(V)=f(\mathrm{span}(\mathbf{v}_{1},\dots, \mathbf{v}_{n}))=f\left\{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}\mathbf{v}_{i}\right\}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}\tag{c}
\mathrm{span}(f(\mathbf{v}_{1}),\dots, f(\mathbf{v}_{n}))
=\left\{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \lambda_{i} f(\mathbf{v}_{i})\right\}=\left\{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} f(\lambda_{i}\mathbf{v}_{i}) \right\}=\left\{ f\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}\mathbf{v}_{i}\right\}
\end{align*}
for some $\lambda_{i}\in \mathbb{K}$. Now I need to find a way to prove that $f\left\{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}\mathbf{v}_{i}\right\}= \left\{ f\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}\lambda_{i}\mathbf{v}_{i}\right\}$ but don't know how. Is there a general property of maps that I somehow missed?

Comment: $f(A)=\{f(x): x\in A\}$

Comment: Yep, that's it... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Julio Puerta basically answers your precise question in the comment section. Yet, you could lighten your proof and make it more readable (and also circumvent your question) by considering a single general vector instead of the whole vector space at the same time. It can be done as a double inclusion.

Let $V$ and $W$ be $\Bbb{K}$-vector spaces, with $V = \mathrm{span}(\mathbf{v}_1,\ldots,\mathbf{v}_n)$ and $f : V \to W$ a linear map. Let be $\mathbf{v} = \sum_i\lambda_i\mathbf{v}_i \in V$. Then, one has
$$
f(\mathbf{v}) = f\left(\sum_i\lambda_i\mathbf{v}_i\right) = \sum_i\lambda_if(\mathbf{v}_i) \in \mathrm{span}(f(\mathbf{v}_1,\ldots,f(\mathbf{v}_n)),
$$
by linearity of $f$, hence $f(V) \subset \mathrm{span}(f(\mathbf{v}_1,\ldots,f(\mathbf{v}_n))$. Now, let's prove the reversed inclusion. Let be $\mathbf{w} = \sum_i\lambda_if(\mathbf{v}_i) \in \mathrm{span}(f(\mathbf{v}_1,\ldots,f(\mathbf{v}_n))$. Then, the same property of linearity permits to write :
$$
\mathbf{w} = \sum_i\lambda_if(\mathbf{v}_i) = f\left(\sum_i\lambda_i\mathbf{v}_i\right) \in f(V),
$$
hence $\mathrm{span}(f(\mathbf{v}_1,\ldots,f(\mathbf{v}_n)) \subset f(V)$ and finally $f(V) = \mathrm{span}(f(\mathbf{v}_1,\ldots,f(\mathbf{v}_n))$. *QED*

Comment: Good idea, I really like that approach, thanks.

Comment: @PAT  You're welcome ;)